# Python script to fetch the details of aws stack layers instances and tags

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-ec2, boto, boto3, aws-opsworks

I would like to fetch the AWS stack details, stack id, no of layers for each stack, no of instances for each layer and their tags using python script. Can some one help me here please.

Comment: What you have tried ?

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import boto3

class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'

print ("\n")
st_name = raw_input("What is STACK_NAME name? :: ")
stack_name = boto3.client('opsworks')
stacs = stack_name.describe_stacks()
for st in stacs['Stacks']:
    stname = st['Name']
    if st_name == stname :
        print bcolors.OKBLUE + ("\nSTACK ID FOR THIS STACK IS :: \n")
        print bcolors.WARNING + st['StackId']
        stid = st['StackId']
        print bcolors.FAIL + (" \nLayers Attached with this STACK and their ID's are :")
        print bcolors.ENDC
        layr = stack_name.describe_layers(StackId=stid)
        for lr in layr['Layers']:
print "LAYER NAME :: " + bcolors.OKGREEN +lr['Name'] +  bcolors.ENDC + " LAYER ID is :: " + bcolors.OKBLUE + lr['LayerId']
```

Sample output:

[image: output]

Comment: check the link below to view sample output :    https://s17.postimg.org/l6fhb8uu7/Screen_Shot_2017-11-26_at_2.05.38_AM.png